# Tahoe Won't Start - Video

Tags: engine, starting, tahoe

Backstory:  My 2004 Tahoe has been losing coolant and I thought Oil for a bit now.  I think it is the intake gaskets but can't do anything about it at the moment.  I've been adding coolant as needed as well as oil.  However, I think I actually have had too much oil in which may be the issue in the first place.

Now on to my main question.  The other day my daughter was driving and the battery light came on, the power steering stopped working and the car seemed to be shutting down.  Thankfully she was able to get it into a parking spot.

My first thought was alternator.  I took the battery to autozone and they said it was down to 11.  So they charged it.  I thought that with a full charge the engine should start and at least I could drive it home.

However, here is what it did instead:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-3ni-VhFFrAWUZnUnpNNHN5Nlk

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, neither oil nor coolant goes through the intake manifold. The intake manifold gaskets only deal with the air coming in through the intake. They are pretty robust gaskets and don't need changing, even if you pull the intake off you won't have to change them most times (unless you damage them). The 5.3L (LM7) engines are known to drink a little oil (my '06 Silvy does). This is a fairly normal occurrence. If the battery was down to 11%, there's an issue in your charging system, either you battery or alternator. This wouldn't preclude it from starting once the battery is recharged, though.

Comment: Open to suggestion, but I have to fill coolant every couple of weeks and these pages are what made me think it was the intake manifold.

https://www.google.com/search?q=Tahoe+Gaskets+Coolant+Leak&oq=Tahoe+Gaskets+Coolant+Leak&aqs=chrome..69i57.3750j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8